# Forwarding Invites on Microsoft Outlook-Does it only send to forwarded recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If I forwarded a calendar invite to Person B and C that I received from Person A who also included a bunch of other recipients, will the email only reach Person B and C? or will it also forward to Person A and all the other recipients?

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding only sends the messages to the recipients you specify.

In an Exchange Server environment, Person A may see that others have received the invitation, but that depends on configuration.